# php Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION on construct

Tags: php, syntax-error

hey guys was hoping you could help me out..

just to let u know in advance, im a relatively new php coder, doing a practice project, and came across this problem and ive spent like an hour of rechecking and googling but just cant figure out whats causing it

error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION in C:\wamp\www\forum\classes\ClassUser.php on line 7

the segment of the code causing the problem:

```
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."forum/classes/general.inc";
Class User{


__construct($u,$p){ //this is line 7

    $user=$u;
    if(strlen($p)>30|| empty($p) || !preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/i',$p)){
    $password=0;

    }
    else{
    $password=hash_hmac('md5',$p,KEY);

    }

}
```

oh and since im new to php, incase im doing something which i should not be, please to recommend.. thanks in advance.

note:ive removed the php tags  since they seemed to be messing with the formatting of this post :/

note2: im also getting another notice
Notice: Use of undefined constant KEY - assumed 'KEY' in C:\wamp\www\forum\classes\general.inc on line 20

but im assuming thats more of a warning than an error... but just adding incase it has something to do with the error

general.inc:

```
//error definations
define("ERROR_FIELD_EMPTY","Error! All required fields not filled");
define("ERROR_INVALID_SIGNIN","Error! Username/password do not match!");
define("ERROR_GENERAL_INPUT", "Error! Invalid input given");
define("ERROR_SQL_CONNECT","Error! Could not connect to sql database");


//field sizes
define("PASSWORD_LENGTH",12);
define("USERNAME_LENGTH",30);

//sql server details
define("SQL_SERVER_NAME","localhost");
define("SQL_SERVER_USERNAME","root");
define("SQL_SERVER_PASSWORD","");
define("SQL_SERVER_DATABASE","forums");

define(KEY,"key");


function __autoload($className){
    require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."forum/classes/Class$className.php");

}
```

ClassUser.php

```
  include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."forum/classes/general.inc";
    Class User{


    __construct($u,$p){

        $user=$u;
        if(strlen($p)>30|| empty($p) || !preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/i',$p)){
        $password=0;

        }
        else{
        $password=hash_hmac('md5',$p,KEY);

        }

    }

    public function validate(){
        if(strlen($user)>30|| empty($user) || preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/i',$password==0 )){
        throw new Exception(ERROR_GENERAL_INPUT);



        }
        $user=mysql_real_escape_string($user);
        return true;

    }

    public function insert(){
       // this->validate();

        $conn= mysqli_connect(SQL_SERVER_NAME,SQL_SERVER_USERNAME,SQL_SERVER_PASSWORD,SQL_SERVER_DATABASE);


        if(empty($conn)){
        throw new Exception(ERROR_SQL_CONNECT);
        }

        $query="INSERT into USERS VALUES ($user,$password)";
        $conn->query($query);



    }

    private $user;
    private $password;

    };
```

NewUser.php

```
 include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."forum/classes/general.inc";




    try{
    $user = new User($_POST['UserName'],$_POST['Password']);
    $user->insert();
    }

    catch(Exception $Error){
    echo $Error->getMessage();


    }
```

Comment: See the manual on constructors: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `__construct` needs to have the word `function` in front of it, or better yet `public function`, in the same way as the other methods in the class (ie `validate` and `insert` in your case).

ie you need the following:

```
public function __construct($u,$p){ //this is line 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line to:

```
public function __construct($u, $p) {
```